# install ubuntu on an external hard disc

Tags: grub2, uninstall, external-hdd

Not long ago I bought a new PC brand Lenovo. I make W7 install because some Windows programs interest me and I need them. From the Ubuntu website I downloaded 14.04. LTS and I burned on a DVD. 
Now it turns out that I have a mess: when I installed Ubuntu I did not think to remove an external drive and Ubuntu is distributed between internal and external hard drive. When I start the machine I get grub to choose the operating system I want to open.

I thought it would be better to remove Ubuntu and install it on a new external drive.

What do you think about? Nor do I know how to uninstall Ubuntu. 
Thank you.

Comment: I think you tried to install to the external drive but GRUB got installed to the internal one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)