# External hard drive installation question

Tags: external-hdd

I see everyone is talking about partitioning and stuff for installing Ubuntu on external hard drives...

If I buy an external hard drive solely for Ubuntu, do I need to do partitioning and stuff if all of it's capacity will be for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope!

As long as you want to use the entire thing as Ubuntu, you're fine. If you want to have some for a backup of something else, or another OS you do need to partition.

[How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive) is an excellent guide to installing on an external drive.

Comment: Which would you recommend out of http://goo.gl/eIUrYV or http://goo.gl/FlSJN4 ?

Comment: @EdStJohn I prefer Seagate to Toshiba personally, but when you're spending £42.71 on it, you might as well spend an extra £6 and go up to 1TB. http://goo.gl/Fz8MFj is the one I use for my backups and second operating systems - and it's pretty good. I've had it a while and trust it with my primary backup. Not worrying about it breaking if it falls off my desk is a massive relief too. However, I'd go for the second one you linked to - just in black, to match my setup ;-) Hope that helps!

Comment: Just wondering - would I be able to install and run Ubuntu on this - http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00YFI1A66/ref=twister_B00TU5RW20?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @EdStJohn Sure, that would work the same.

Comment: Why doesn't everyone go with that then? They are so much more portable I might get that?

Comment: @EdStJohn They can be more volatile, and have less protection. It's easier to loose, and portability isn't needed when you're booting an OS; reliablility is.

Comment: I see what you mean, but as a laptop user moving about, portability and slimness is a very big factor for me personally. What do you mean by unreliable? What will go wrong if I use it?

Comment: @EdStJohn Oh it's not a massive issue, but hdds often have longer lives than ssds - especially when used to boot an OS. I doubt it will be an issue for you!

Comment: Going with the seagate - safer

Comment: Tim someone just recommended this SSD to me - says it's a lot faster but it has 350GB less storage on it for same price. Does the speed affect it a lot from the seagate to this? http://www.misco.co.uk/productinfo/productinfo?productCode=2152206&affiliate=GOOGLEPLA&cm_mmc=google-_-Product_PlusBox-__-2152206&catargetid=530001250000398687&cadevice=m&gclid=Cj0KEQiAjMC2BRC34oGKqY27jtkBEiQAwSXzfoTFR_R-cTd4KiUXx6vwT_O0Xe8dSOPeWb9jrCjlsrkaAsVT8P8HAQ

Comment: IMO 128 is too small - I'm not a typical user but I have 1.1 TB of data, including 840.5 GB in my home area. It means you will get faster boot times, but note that is limited by the USB connection. I would chose the one I currently have over that but you may need faster boots - especially if you're moving your laptop about.

Comment: Going with the seagate then ;)

Comment: Is there much use getting a 1TB over 500GB? I've only used 100GB on windows so I don't think I need that much?

Comment: Well from my view there is no disadvantage - it's £6 more and double the space. More storage space never hurt anyone ;-)

Comment: This might be a stupid question but when booting up do I still have to use the USB for booting or will it boot straight from the external hard drive once installed? ;)

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not need to create partitions in that case. However you *could* create some. It is often done in this way:

- One partition for "/"
- One for swap
- One for your personal data (home)

Comment: Ok thanks. Sorry what is swap and / ? New to this aha

Comment: "/" is the root directory, that is where the system will be located (similar to C:\ in Windows). The swap partition is for virtual memory, used typically when the RAM is full (similar to pagefile.sys in some Windows). I think it is possible to *not* create a swap partition and instead have a swap file located in the root directory. It is also possible to have your home dir on the same partition as the root dir.

Comment: Is it possible for the Ubuntu installer to do all that for me or do I have to do that myself?

Comment: The Ubuntu installer comes with a partitioning tool and will do it. Of course, you will have to indicate what you want: which size for which partition. But if you are sure you will only have one system on this drive, you might as well go for the single partition.