# Installing to an external HDD

Tags: system-installation

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Z50-75 laptop with Windows 10 on a 256GB SSD, Lenovo A4CN40WW (v.2.09) UEFI BIOS, AMD A10-7300 Radeon R6 processor, and a Broadcom 802.11 network adapter.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 16.04 on an external SATA USB HDD including the bootloader?

Comment: [Looks like it can be done](http://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive), as long as your bios has an option to boot from a USB HD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can. And I've done it before. However the OS will then run generally *very* slow. So what I recommend (and what I tend to do) is learn how to swap the hard drive out easily and I bring screwdriver with me. I have a Lenovo laptop and my laptop bag has SSDs and a screwdriver. I find that I can do a swap in 15 minutes but it's worth it if you don't need to swap the OS that often.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I prefer not to use the screwdriver installation method.