# Can't remove Ubuntu from HDD even after deleting the partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows-10

I'm really new to Linux in general. So I had installed Ubuntu on one of the partitions in my HDD while keeping Windows 10 on the SSD (single partition). Today I went to install Ubuntu on the SSD in a separate partition, before which, I followed [this](https://notesread.com/how-to-delete-an-ubuntu-hard-drive-partition-from-windows/) guide to remove it from the HDD.

The **first block of (D:)** disk in the image was the one having Ubuntu on it. I deleted it & extended the next block of **(D:)** disk to take up the unallocated space.

[image]

I can see the **(D:)** disk as a single partition in the windows explorer-

[image]

However, I still get the earlier Ubuntu option in the Boot menu. And in newly installed Ubuntu (on SSD), I see the entire HDD with following contents-

[image]

What went wrong in removing the OS? How do I fix it?

Comment: The boot menu is called a boot loader. It loads before Ubuntu or Windows or any operating system loads. Part of the boot loader resides in a special partition called EFI System Partition, or ESP in short. See [Part 1: Remove Ubuntu entry from the EFI partition in the internal disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036723/can-only-boot-windows-10-through-grub-how-do-i-disable-this/1036740#1036740) for an answer to a similar problem. Also see the [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi) linked above.

Comment: You have Windows dynamic partitions. That is proprietary to Microsoft and is not related nor does not work with Linux. Typically not required now that Windows in UEFI mode uses gpt partitioning. It was a work around for the 4 primary partition limit with MBR partitioning instead of the more common primary, extended & logical partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325331&p=13492758&viewfull=1#post13492758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably installed the new Ubuntu on the SSD before removing the old one. Upon installation, GRUB is installed. It checks what operating systems exist on the system. Since your old Ubuntu was still there, it was also included in the GRUB menu.

Boot into your Ubuntu session, and run the command `sudo update-grub`. The existing kernels and other operating systems will be probed, resulting in an updated boot menu.

That you still may see the files of the old install is apparently related to the fact that this disk uses Windows dynamic partitions. I would not touch that drive using Linux tools. Deleting that partition from within linux probably would delete it effectively, but may damage the dynamic partitioning.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. But I don't know why the Windows file explorer never shows the SSD partition running Ubuntu (see the image in the question). Is it normal?