# How to install ubuntu 17.10 on an external hard drive?

Tags: system-installation

Till now, What I have found about this topic is tons of “senior” Linux vetrans saying weird, complicated and unhelpful steps on how to install ubuntu on an external hard drive,

I just don't seem to get it right because what I do is...

1. download the ISO file
2. create a bootable USB using Rufus
3. choose something else from the Ubuntu installation screen
4. formate my external hard drive partitions to use ext4 as suggested
5. install ubuntu....
6. restart my PC
7. press the key that leads to the boot screen
8. select the USB HDD on which I installed Ubuntu
9. windows 10 starts .

What am I doing wrong??????????

Comment: Really, open source communities are faster than Microsoft to respond

Comment: it could be a hardware issue, eg.  a dell i have will only boot an external USB drive IF there is only one drive attached (by default i have three usb devices usually attached). Also a printer we may not think of as an 'drive' can be if it allows sharing of files (eg. includes a scanner).  You removed your installer-thumb-drive?

Comment: I have just unboxed the external hdd I'm talking about.

Comment: So what do you want now? Do you still want help according to your question, or something else? If you still want help, maybe this link is helpful, [Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

Comment: **Done:** You must also make the computer boot from USB. This is done in the UEFI/BIOS system, either with a hotkey to get a temporary boot menu, where you can select USB, or by changing the boot order in some menu. -- **To do(?):** If UEFI mode, you may have to turn off secure boot. In Windows it may help to turn off fast startup (a kind of semi-hibernation). There are many versions of UEFI/BIOS systems, and you must learn how to manage the systems in the computer(s), where you want to boot your portable Ubuntu system. (This belongs to the computer and is independent of Ubuntu.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

Ok..you downloaded the iso file, good!...DO NOT create a bootable usb stick, create a bootable dvd instead...take Rufus out for a walk and leave it tied to a tree. next..start your computer and enter the bios and make these settings on the "boot order" first boot device...CD DVD ROM!!..second boot device..USB HARD DRIVE..now follow me, your new usb hdd must be readied for what you are about to throw at it,..most newer17.10> linux distros will have a program pre-installed called "gparted". With your new usb hdd plugged in, install the newly created ubuntu iso dvd in the drive and FORCEFULLY shut down your computer with the power switch!..now re-start your machine and wait for the ubuntu disk to bring you to the desktop, now snoop around in the apps and find "gparted", click on it, it will show all your drives, find your external hdd and click on it.Dedicate the entire drive to ubuntu using the ext3 filesystem not ext4..once the drive is partitioned and formatted the following step is very important..go to the top bar of gparted where it says "partition" and scroll down to where it says "manage flags" and click the box that says "BOOT"..your finished now shut down normally ,restart and send ubuntu to the external drive...when done dont forget to take out the install disk before you re-boot to your new usb hdd..cheers

Comment: And if the OP does not have a DVD drive?