# About How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?

Tags: 16.04, usb-drive, external-hdd

Thank you @chaskes for your explanation [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)
I tried to add this question as comment beneath you answer but I don't have 50 reputation
They are 6 questions about your answer

1. Will this Ubuntu on external Hard Drive work normally as if installed on a laptop as normaly OS?
2. Can I move this Ubuntu from the external Hard Drive to the Hard Disk of a new laptop and make this Ununtu as if installed initially on the new laptop?
3. Every time I run this Ubuntu on external Hard Drive on a another laptop not the usual one will I need to install the drivers of the adapters of the other laptop?
4. If I have external Hard Drive with 1TB how much the swap should I choose?
5. Does Ubuntu nowadays still in no need for any Antivirus?
6. If I run Ubuntu on external Hard Drive on a laptop can I access the the hadr disk of the laptop?

And thank you very much

Comment: I know answer for question number 5.  Configure appArmor. Never run code or install program from external source which is not trusted. You will be always safe in Ubuntu.I you want more security, Just have clamtk on demand scanner.  For past 1 year only 1 browser infection due to my own mistake. I am 10 times secure in Ubuntu without live time antivirus protection then in windows with paid antivirus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that @chaskes will find your question and give you an answer :-)

But I will also try to answer your questions, starting with a reference to my answer to a corresponding question,

[Boot Ubuntu from external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786986/boot-ubuntu-from-external-drive/942312#942312)

---

> 1. Will this Ubuntu on external Hard Drive work normally as if installed on a laptop as normaly OS?

Yes, except that

- it might be slower than if connected internally via SATA. USB3 is quite fast, but USB 2 is rather slow
- discard (for an SSD) does not work via USB

> 2. Can I move this Ubuntu from the external Hard Drive to the Hard Disk of a new laptop and make this Ubuntu as if installed initially on
>      the new laptop?

Yes, but check that

- the target drive has the same size or is bigger (not one single byte smaller), if you want to clone it
- the physical sector sizes are the same on the source drive and the target drive
- if proprietary drivers, that they match the target computer.

Otherwise you should copy at the file level, install the bootloader and do some other fixes, or simply make a fresh installation, if you think the fixes are too complicated. In this case you can copy the `/home` directory to a 'home' partition for the fresh installation.

> 3. Every time I run this Ubuntu on external Hard Drive on a another laptop not the usual one will I need to install the drivers of the
>      adapters of the other laptop?

If no proprietary drivers are installed, the free linux drivers are used. If the target computer, 'the other computer', works with the free drivers, you need not install any drivers. But some hardware, for example new and powerful nvidia graphics cards and Broadcom wifi cards need proprietary drivers.

> 4. If I have external Hard Drive with 1TB how much the swap should I choose?

It depends on how you use the computer.

- If you want to hibernate, you need as much as the RAM (in gibibytes) and a little bit more, for example 4 GiB RAM ~ 4.3 GB RAM --> 5 GB swap,
- otherwise it is probably enough with 2 GB swap unless you know, that you need a lot of swap for some particular application.

> 5. Does Ubuntu nowadays still in no need for any Antivirus?

That has not changed.

> 6. If I run Ubuntu on external Hard Drive on a laptop can I access the hard disk of the laptop?

Yes, but

- if Windows is hibernated or semi-hibernated (fast startup), then linux stays away from it to avoid corruption. So if you want access to Windows partitions, please avoid hibernation and turn off fast startup in Windows.

Comment: You are welcome @moamarlinux :-)

Answer (score -1):

1. yes it will run like it was installed on a HDD
2. No, it is generally not portable because during installation decisions have been made
   depending on the current hardware. Live USB systems are portable.
3. Probably yes unless the hardware is the same
4. The needed size of the swap depends on usage and the 
   size of the memory.
5. I will not even try to answer this question.
6. Yes, if you mount it and if the laptop's operating system allows it
   (e.g. a hibernated windows will not permit writing on its disk).

NB: You should only ask one question per "question" here.