# Ubuntu on external hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, laptop, windows-10, external-hdd, acer

So what I want is to have windows 10 on the internal drive of my laptop and ubuntu on an external hard drive. I know this is possible but what I don't know, is what happens when I wouldn't have the external drive connected. Would I still be able to boot into windows? Or would I need to have the drive connected so that I can choose the OS in grub/bootloader?

Would it matter in which order I install the OSes?

Does anyone know a good tutorial I can follow? I can't seem to find one for what I'm looking for exactly.

Comment: Did you search Ask Ubuntu for your subject line?  Does https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive answer your main questions?  It seems to provide a detailed set of instructions and the post includes the statement "Choose the one you want. If you boot without the usb, you will boot into Windows normally."

Comment: How is Windows 10 installed (legacy or UEFI). Does your BIOS/UEFI Settings allow you to boot either with a preference for one over the other? Can you remove the internal disk when you install to the external disk?  See bug 1173457 for UEFI issues.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)