# How to install Ubuntu on a Dell Inspiron 1525 which has no operating system

Tags: laptop, external-hdd, usb-installation

I have a Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop, which has had the os removed and hard disk wiped. I downloaded the latest version of Ubuntu desktop onto an external hard drive. I am struggling on the Dell laptop to access the external hard drive and install ubuntu.
I have changed the boot sequence on the Dell so that USB drive is no.1, but still not able to access the external hard drive & load ubuntu.
Can anyone help?
Thanks
Kevin

Comment: If you don't have any os, then you will need another computer to make a bootable usb. From this bootable usb you can install ubuntu. All this information can be found on internet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive) and [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/q/674441/)

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you put ubuntu(or Lbuntu lighter version) on the USB instead of the external drive.  That will be the easiest way to get it running. Otherwise I think you will have to manually mount the external drive so that is recognized.