# Which installation method do I use if I have win 10 on an internal SSD and want to dual boot linux on an external SSD?

Tags: dual-boot

(Before you read this post I am extraordinarily new to Linux and dual booting and all that jazz.)

I have windows as my main OS on an internal hard drive on my PC. However I want to try using linux and I don't want to outright replace windows as there are some games/software that I know linux cannot handle very easily or without loads of configuring, and I have a totally blank external SSD I want to install linux onto and run it on (and with trial and error, I know how to install).
What's getting me is I'm not sure which setting to use when I'm on the install screen - Install ubuntu alongside (my main OS) or Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu? My knowledge of BIOS and Dual booting is not very great.

From what I understand, the first option sounds ideal, but I'm not sure if it will let me "dual boot" (or choose which OS to use every time my computer restarts) since  windows and linux would be on two separate drives. The other option sounds more straightforward as there's nothing to wipe and would just be a straight installation, but from what I understand no dual booting would be available.

which installation option should I choose?

Comment: Responses maybe be more useful/accurate if you're specific as to what Ubuntu product you're trying to install; what release that is & what ISO you're using. Ubuntu is available in many ISOs for download; some contain different installers; so what you see can vary from one if compared to another.  Currently you've provided no specifics (Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Core.. what release you're talking about, if it's the main ISO, an alternate etc.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate Hard Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)

Comment: You must partition in advance using gpt partitioning and have the ESP - efi system partition on external drive. Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs grub2's boot loader to first drive, usually internal drive. If always using external with same system that works, but often better to have boot files on external drive. LInks in above comments seem to cover that, but some similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130372/dual-booting-win-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-two-separate-physical-ssds Old but current bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379