# Install Ubuntu 18.04 in portable external ssd

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, portable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koAe9.jpg)I am using this tutorial to install Ubuntu 18.04:

https://www.58bits.com/blog/2020/02/28/how-create-truly-portable-ubuntu-installation-external-usb-hdd-or-ssd

all working good till it install in external ssd. (till step D)

but when i started step E to make it truly portable. After i follow step by step. It will show me error on booting in external ssd with try ubuntu menu that "Install kernal first".

Help me to make the external ssd truly portable.

Comment: which steps in E did you do? All of it? Where did you get stuck? can you describe exactly what you did to try and boot up when you got stuck?

Comment: @Esther I completely followed Step E and at the end it shows grub installed succesfully , no error reported then when i try to test that the ssd become portable or not. I restart my pc and give boot from usb drive higher preference and try to boot in portable ssd but it open the menu with options try ubuntu install ubuntu and when i click any of this option i got an error message you need to load kernel first. So i basically want to say ubuntu installed completely and it runs on the laptop in which it is installed but not portable as i run it in another laptop it cant boot.

Comment: did you boot from USB drive or from external SSD? not the same thing

Comment: after step E i boot from external ssd in which all the installation process happened.

Comment: The drive you installed Ubuntu on shouldn't have the "try ubuntu" option at all. It should just boot. Are you sure you followed all the steps correctly?

Comment: yes i followed every step correctly. Even i did it twice. But same error occurs.

Comment: can you show screenshots so I can see what's happening?

Comment: @ESther i just added the screenshot.

Comment: Why do you have a "try ubuntu" option? Are you booting from the correct drive?

Comment: Yes I boot from external ssd. me also dont understand why this occurs.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)

Comment: @oldfred http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WWVC794txd/

Comment: Line 112 shows boot entry for T7. But ubuntu entry on internal drive's ESP will only work if T7 plugged in. So does it boot? It looks like GUID/partUUID & UUIDs all refer to correct partitions. If you can boot with "ubuntu" entry, do a total reinstall of grub, so it fully is installed in T7's ESP. Or use Boot-Repair's advanced mode and choose total reinstall of grub to T7 drive. How new is system? You may need 22.04 to have latest drivers & kernel.

Comment: @oldfred i need to install ubuntu 18.04 specifically.  Ok then from boot repairs reinstalling the grub in T7. Lets hope it works.

Comment: As noted in the posted link: "Update: 07-02-2021 - C.S.Cameron posted this to askubuntu.com - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step  Although I've not tested this yet - it's a great post and appears to support both UEFI and older BIOS/MBR configurations."

Comment: @oldfred error while installing grub to t7 and also dont know how to do that from boot repair tool.

Comment: What error? And Boot-Repair has advanced options where you select to totally install grub and choose drive. Be sure to boot live installer in UEFI mode or you get error. Shows advanced mode screens: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/