# How to install Ubuntu in live ubuntu usb external hard disk

Tags: 18.04

I have an external hard disk of 1TB which I have converted to a Live ubuntu USB external drive. My question is can I install Ubuntu in same live ubuntu USB external drive. If yes then how to do it.

How to install Ubuntu in live ubuntu usb external hard disk

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/q/855039/43926

Comment: Today, with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, a partition labeled 'writable' might be mounted, and you don't want that. So boot with the boot options `toram` and `nopersistent` to avoid that, and then you can unmount also that partition. Maybe you want to keep the live system. Then you can put the installed system into the partition labeled 'writable'.

Comment: If UEFI system for UEFI boot, you must partition in advance & use gpt. If UEFI, you can create a 5 or 6GB FAT32 partition  as ESP for install & extract ISO into it for booting. I would create a smaller ESP for booting once installed. Note that Ubquity installer will only install boot files to first drive, normally your internal drive. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Work arounds in report & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)