# Can I install Ubuntu on external USB-HDD? And will that affect on my windows

Tags: 22.04, hard-drive, windows

I have external HDD with 900gb of free space can I install Ubuntu and will not affect on my windows?

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Grub installs to wrong disk. Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list on the bug.
There are workarounds/solutions in the bug comments. Another problem is that your host system probably will not boot without the external device (since needed grub files are on it). Ubuntu 23.04  with a different installer will install grub where you indicate.

Comment: So I need 23.04 to boot windows W/o external drive?

Comment: From what I understand, if you install 23.04, then it will install the grub bootloader to the external drive. Then, if the external drive is connected, the computer will give you the option to dual boot, but when disconnected, it will boot straight into Windows. It seems that previous versions of Ubuntu installer had a bug that might mess things up, and you might have trouble booting to Windows without the external drive

Comment: No during install, you need to make sure you have an ESP on external drive and install Ubuntu/grub UEFI boot files to the external drive's ESP. 22.04 and prior used Ubiquity installer which has the bug. Shows a choice on where to install boot files, but does not work. New version now use Subiquity installer, which supposed lets you choose which drive to install boot files into and works. Have not tested it myself.

Comment: So I should use 23.04 on external hard drive if I have plans to use windows without external hard drive?

Comment: @oldfred So, unless properly configured, Ubuntu 22.04 and prior will install to the external drive but that will fail to boot (and will boot straight to Windows). Is that correct?

Comment: It depends on your UEFI settings. I have multiple installs on various flash drives &  external SSD (SSD much better for external booting). When you unplug a drive, UEFI "forgets settings" External drives need to be booted directly from UEFI. You can set Windows as default & if external plugged in, boot external first. Same as choosing to boot installer. You can have "ubuntu" entry to boot external, but many UEFI lose setting when drive unplugged.

Comment: So if I unplug mine external hdd it will automatically boot into windows so I shouldn’t care about what version I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)