# Installing Ubuntu on USB-HDD

Tags: 22.04, windows, windows-10, usb-drive, 23.04

I want to install Ubuntu on my external hard drive, but I want to use windows when I unplugged usb-hdd. How to make that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question, there's a similar inquiry available [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1467480/install-bootable-ubuntu-on-external-ssd-without-changing-windows-10). Please take a look.

Furthermore, after you've completed the installation, **make sure to adjust the boot order in the BIOS settings to give priority to the USB disk**. Without this adjustment, the system won't automatically start up into Ubuntu when the USB is connected.

Here's how the boot order should be arranged:

```
1. Your USB device containing Ubuntu
2. Your internal Windows hard disk or SSD
3. Any additional devices like DVDs, etc.
```

Once you've made these changes in the BIOS and saved them, your setup should be ready to go.